# Binding a textbox from a secondary window is not updating the property

Tags: wpf, binding, window

I need to bind the text property of a textbox that it is located in a secondary window to a property that is defined in the corresponding view model of that secondary window

XAML CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="RG.IOManager.Views.PreferencesDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:genericClasses="clr-namespace:RG.IOManager.GenericClasses"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="Setup" Height="131" Width="332"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    >

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../ScrollBarTemplate.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Cycle Time"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,20" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="190" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!--
        <xctk:IntegerUpDown  Name="TbMainCycleTime" Margin="10,10,0,20" Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                             Increment="1" Maximum="5000" Minimum="0" ShowButtonSpinner="False"/>
        -->

        <TextBox Name="TbMainCycleTime" Margin="10,10,0,20" Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxErrorTooltip}" >
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Source="PreferencesDialog" Path="CycleTime" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <genericClasses:IntegersValidation Min="0" Max="1000" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <!--<TextBox Name="TbMainCycleTime" Margin="10,10,0,20" Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  />-->
        <Label Content="ms" Margin="1,10,10,20"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="190" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Update" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0" Name="btUpdate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btUpdate_Click" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,10,0" Name="btCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btCancel_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

CS CODE:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for PreferencesDialogue.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class PreferencesDialog : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Binding Properties

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Main cycle time
    /// </summary>
    public int CycleTime
    {
        get { return _CycleTime; }
        set
        {
            _CycleTime = value;
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CycleTime"));
            }
        }
    }
    private int _CycleTime;

    #endregion


    private IOManager _receiver;

    public PreferencesDialog(IOManager receiver)
    {
        this._receiver = receiver;
        InitializeComponent();

        //this.TbMainCycleTime.Text = _receiver.globalBindingProperties.MainCycleTime.ToString();
        this.CycleTime = _receiver.globalBindingProperties.MainCycleTime;
    }


    private void btUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _receiver.globalBindingProperties.MainCycleTime = Convert.ToInt32(this.TbMainCycleTime.Text);
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to find what i did wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us place in code, where was DataContext assigned?

Comment: The window tag <Window x:Class="RG.IOManager.Views.PreferencesDialog" ...> </window> defines the class where the property "CycleTime" is  don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your approach is wrong. however if you change these two thing your problem will be solved:

first set DataContext of the Window:

```
    public PreferencesDialog(IOManager receiver)
{
    this.DataContext = this;

    this._receiver = receiver;
    InitializeComponent();

    //this.TbMainCycleTime.Text = _receiver.globalBindingProperties.MainCycleTime.ToString();
    this.CycleTime = _receiver.globalBindingProperties.MainCycleTime;
}
```

second remove 'Source' from TextBox.Text.Binding since the source is the dataContext.

```
    <TextBox Name="TbMainCycleTime" Margin="10,10,0,20" Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxErrorTooltip}" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="CycleTime" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <genericClasses:IntegersValidation Min="0" Max="1000" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned your viewmodel as datacontext to window? (class in which you have defined CycleTime)

Secondly, are you going to change cycle time for UI. You are using two way binding between TextBox and CycleTime property.

Check if this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296256/Type-safe-textbox-in-Silverlight), where I've created type safe text box extnsions. Though, article is about silverlight, you can easily use in WPF.

Change your xaml as

```
<Window x:Class="RG.IOManager.Views.PreferencesDialog" x:Name="PreferencesDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

Comment: How can i assign the class "PreferencesDialog" as datacontext to the window. I thought that i had alreday did that because the window tag includes the class "PreferencesDialog"  -> <Window x:Class="RG.IOManager.Views.PreferencesDialog" ... />

Comment: I am bit worried with the kind of code you have written. Please try to google for "WPF MVVM" and see how to use viewmodel as datacontext to view (Window/ control)

Comment: I try to alter the xaml but i get this error when i compile : "The member names couldn't be equal to the corresponding surrounding members"